# Would equipping Skullclamp cause Polyraptor to trigger?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Would adding a +1/-1 token to [Polyraptor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Polyraptor) with [Skullclamp](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Skullclamp) count as “damage” and trigger Polyraptor? I am guessing the answer is “no”. That this is just an adjustment to toughness, not damage.

Comment: By the way, there's no such thing as a "+1/-1 token" in Magic. You might be thinking of things like +1/+1 counters and -1/-1 counters, but counters are different from tokens, and if something puts those counters on a creature, it will literally use the words "+1/+1 counter" or "-1/-1 counter" (or it will reference an ability, like explore, whose definition literally uses those words). Skullclamp doesn't say anything about counters, so it just gives the creature +1/-1 which is not represented by a token or counter or anything.

Answer (score 10):

You're right, the answer is "no". Giving a creature -1 to toughness can kill an indestructible creature, for example, but any amount of damage cannot kill an indestructible creature. No damage is done; Polyraptor does not trigger.

By the way Skullclamp does not give a "+1/-1 token". It gives a +1/-1 effect. Tokens, like the ones created by [Raise the Alarm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Raise%20the%20Alarm), are actual permanents that stay on the battlefield until removed. Skullclamp's effect disappears once it's moved to another creature.